# Aggregator pattern in Mirth

Tags: mirth

I am receiving a large number of correlated HL7 messages in Mirth. They contain an ID which is always the same for all correlated messages and they always come within a minute. Multiple batches can be received at the same time. It's hard to say when the batch ends, but when there are no more messages for a minute, it's safe to assume that the batch has finished.

How could I implement an aggregator pattern in Mirth that would keep reading and completing correlated messages and send the completed message after it didn't receive any new messages with the same ID within a defined time interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this by saving all messages in a folder using an ID inside the message (that identifies the sequence) as the file name. The file gets updated with each new message. Several sequences live together in the same folder.

The next channel is using a simple file reader that only fetches the files that are a minute or more old.

Answer (score 1):

You may drop all incoming message to a folder and store the message ID in a Global Map. Once new messages start to arrive with the message ID different than the one stored in the map (meaning that the next sequence is started), trigger another channel either by sending the message ID it needs to look for or in some other way. After that replace the message ID in the Global Map with the message ID of a new sequence.

If that sounds too complicated, you may do the same, but the second channel will constantly scan the folder (File Reader) and grab only files having the same message ID and older than a minute from a current time (which is in my mind is too vague qualifier).

Comment: This will only work, if the sequences don't mix. But your answer helped me to figure it out.

Comment: I'd suggest you work on implementing HL7 continuation protocol in a correct way. Then it will not matter if sequence does or does not mix. Btw, which version of HL7 is that?